# sp_ExecuteSql: The parameterized query expects the parameter @XX, which was not supplied

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameterized-query

I'm trying to build a dynamic stored procedure to allow me to pass my string where clause as part of the parameter. However, following [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188001.aspx) from MSDN I still couldn't get it running and having the error as described by the title. Any help is much appreciated.

```
EXEC    [dbo].[Get_Demand_By_Click_Test]        
        @Year = 2014
```

Error:

> Msg 8178, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>   The parameterized query '(@Year int)
>      SELECT
>      dbo.vw_Demand_By.*
>   FROM       '
>   expects the parameter '@Year', which was not supplied.

Stored procedure:

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_demand_by_click_test]
     @Year INT
  AS
  BEGIN
      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
      -- interfering with SELECT statements.
      SET nocount ON;

      -- Insert statements for procedure here
      DECLARE @SQL             NVARCHAR(max),
              @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(max)

      SET @SQL = N'
SELECT       
dbo.vw_Demand_By.*

FROM            
dbo.vw_Demand_By 

WHERE  
Year(EventStartDate) = @Year'

   SET @ParamDefinition = N'@Year int';

      EXECUTE Sp_executesql
        @SQL,
        @ParamDefinition;
  END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give a value to the @Year parameter. To execute the code use:

```
  EXECUTE Sp_executesql
    @SQL,
    @ParamDefinition,
    @Year = 2014
```

**UPDATE**
In response to your comments you can assign any variable in the place of the fixed 2014 value. In your code it will look like :

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_demand_by_click_test]
     @Year INT
  AS
  BEGIN
      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
      -- interfering with SELECT statements.
      SET nocount ON;

      -- Insert statements for procedure here
      DECLARE @SQL             NVARCHAR(max),
              @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(max)

      SET @SQL = N'

SELECT       
dbo.vw_Demand_By.*

FROM            
dbo.vw_Demand_By 

WHERE  
Year(EventStartDate) = @Year'

   SET @ParamDefinition = N'@Year int';

      EXECUTE Sp_executesql
        @SQL,
        @ParamDefinition,
        @Year = @Year
  END
```

Comment: TYVM, I think this is the solution. As a capstone to the question, if I also adding a parameter query string, for example, '@Wheres = 'Status = ''Cancelled''' to the end of my '@SQL, do I also include this '@Wheres in my '@ParamDefinition? I'm updating my question for this further part.

Comment: `@Wheres = 'Status = 'Cancelled'` is incorrect. You can either hardcode the predicate to `Status = 'Cancelled'` or use a parameter like `Status = @Wheres`. To execute the SQL string you have to pass an exact number of parameters. So if you add into your `@SQL` `@Wheres` you also need to include this in `@ParamDefinition`.

Comment: This is the proper syntax that declares the parameter and SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the parameter as well:

```
EXECUTE Sp_executesql @SQL, @ParamDefinition, @Year = @Year;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I'm aiming to build a dynamic SP, so that @Year will be a variable. How can I do that?

Comment: You have already done that.  But when you run your dynamic SQL, you have to provide a value for your variable.

Comment: Hi Andomar, I might get you wrong, but I've passed in my variable '@Year = 2014 when executing the SP externally, but inside the SP I'd like to pass the parameter '@Year as a variable rather than a fix value 2014. Appreciate if you can point me the right direction.

Comment: To pass the value of a stored procedure parameter to dynamic SQL, use `@Year = @Year`.

Comment: Your answer showed up in the Low Quality Queue. It would be helpful if you made more than a one to two line answer.